# Spark Job getting stuck

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, indexoutofboundsexception, servletexception

I am trying to union 5 data frames in my cod(simple union, no joins). The output data frame contains around 95k records. The cluster is getting stuck and neither running nor failing. It is 4.4x large cluster with 40 nodes.
**Spark Configs** -
--num-executors 120
--executor-cores 5
--executor-memory 38g
--driver-memory 35g
--shuffle.partitions=1400

When I perform spark submit manually, it throws **error** :
**AsyncEventQueue: Dropping event from queue appStatus. This likely means one of the listeners is too slow and cannot keep up with the rate at which tasks are being started by the scheduler.**

I also get a lot of **IndexOutOfBounds** exceptions. The important thing to note here is that there is no fixed dataframe from which this error/exception starts occuring. Can someone help with the possible reasons?

The exceptions have been pasted below

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:848)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1772)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter.doFilter(AmIpFilter.java:166)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:493)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:539)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:333)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:283)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:108)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Please include some context as to what code you're running is giving this error.

Comment: added details @ewong